# Azure web app restarting on BackgroundService

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I need to be able to create an excel report from a web app running on azure. Initially the report was created immediatly but this took to long, so the generation is offloaded to a background worker that creates the report and sends a mail to the user with a download link.

This works but, for small files, but when the size of the report hits about 15MB (which corresponds to about 100k lines in excel) the app service simply restarts without any error whatsoever in the application logs.

The only entry is

`[Information] Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Application is shutting down...`

Running the same code on my local machine with a copy of the database works.

The app is running in an S1 which is fast enough for normal flows. Any suggestions

Comment: That's a big old file. The only way I've been able to get around this issue in the past was by putting it in a standalone console app - seems to be that microsoft kills stuff off if it's been running too long, unless it's console based.

Comment: If I remember correctly, uncaught exception in background service will crash the app. You might try catching the exception and log it to see what causes the exception.

Comment: When your background worker generates such a large excel file, how much memory does it consume, may be the S1 instance type runs out of memory, or exceeds a threshold and so the Az runtime recycles that worker.